# XPath for <td> element

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have a line "line1, line2, line3" in the td tag. However i am interested in getting the line2 as the output using XPath expression.

```
<table class = "class1">
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>
          line 1, line 2, line 3
    </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Any input on this will be helpful

Comment: please post some code . . .

Comment: Any sample markup input and the expected output will be helpful

Comment: @har07 expected output is line 2

Comment: @danielad Have posted the code.

Comment: Have you tried `substring-before(substring-after( X, ','), ',')`? See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring-before

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, I tried substring-after. "line1, line2, line 3 " are dynamic

Comment: @Mondayaccount It shouldn't matter if they are dynamic. CiaPan's suggestion only relies on them being separated by commas.

Comment: @JLRishe- I tried comma separated values

Answer (score 1):

This returns "line 2":

```
/table/tbody/tr/td/normalize-space(tokenize(.,',')[2])
```

What it does, in plain English:

> Look for `td` inside a `tr` element, which is in turn inside a `tbody` element which is inside `table`. Tokenize this `td`, taking a comma as the delimiter of separate tokens. Return the second item in the resulting list. Strip any trailing whitespace with `normalize-space()`.

The expression only works if you can rely on the string parts being delimited by something like a comma.

This makes use of functions that are only available in XPath 2.0. If you tagged this question with `xpath-2.0` by accident, the answer will not help much.

**XSLT Stylesheet for illustration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="/table/tbody/tr/td/normalize-space(tokenize(.,',')[2])"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Text Output**

```
line 2
```